# Visual Studio code metrics plugin for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, metrics

Is there a VS2008 plugin for code metrics for C++? I have Team System but it doesn't work for non- .NET code. I tried studioTools but it just freezes. So, does anyone know one that actually works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out that CodeRush does this.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a plugin, but Source Monitor from http://www.campwoodsw.com/ is a great free metrics tool.

Comment: SourceMonitor is great.  I wish I could give you more points ;)

Comment: Looks like it only support .smp and not .sln solution files for VS